# Is it possible to exit the airport without going through the customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I was a first time traveler and didn't know what to do.  I got my luggage and exited the airport without going through the customs. I didn't pass when I arrived in the country that I travelled to and didn't pass again when I arrived at the country I travelled from.  It's an honest mistake, I just didn't know what to do then until my friend told me.

I am planning to travel again but I am afraid that I may have violated something and they will not allow me to leave.  Can I get penalized?

Comment: What country/airport was this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you did not walk through a passageway which was the customs area? There may not have been anyone on duty there for you to see.

Comment: Are.you _sure_ you didn't pass through the green 'Nothing to declare' channel? I've travelled through many airports around the world and without exception, when I've had to pass through customs there was no other route available.

Comment: You say you didn't go through customs, but did you go through an immigration check?

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't passed through the customs. Am I going to get penalized? Are they going to allow me to leave again?

Comment: @user85638: you should specify which airport (and better: which flight). Only international flight could have customs, but not always.

Comment: "Get penalized" depends if you had stuffs (or money) that you were required to declare, not so much to "passing the custom".

Comment: I doubt there's a single airport in the world that's set up to allow international visitors to just wander out without passing customs when necessary.

Comment: Unless the original asker updates the question with the specific airport and flight in question, I think it's impossible to answer this question. In general the answer is "No, when you depart an international airport you always go through customs", but without the details, it's hard to state there is no way it could happen. I imagine that if the details are provided, someone will provide a photo of exactly what the customs line looks like and show how it's possible to exit through customs without realizing it.

Comment: @user85638 We will need to know exactly what airports were involved, origin and destination.  Without that, any answer is pure speculation.

Comment: @user85638 Also, was your Passport examined at any time?

Answer (score 23):

If you arrived on an international flight, then it's very unlikely that you exited the airport without passing through customs.
It's most likely that you just didn't recognize that you were were passing through customs, because I'm guessing you were expecting some sort of search of your goods or at least a desk where you'd have to explain what you were carrying, etc.
However in many airports you have the option of walking out through a "green" nothing-to-declare zone/passageway which is more-or-less the equivalent of you saying that you don't believe that you're carrying anything of interest to customs.
Often in my experience these green zones don't even have anyone on duty in them, but sometimes they do, and sometimes a passenger passing through the green zone will be stopped and have their belongings checked to make sure they're not trying to import anything they shouldn't be.

So as long as you left the airport the same way all the other passengers did, and didn't sneak out through a side door or something like that, you're fine.

Comment: ... unless he actually had something with him that the _should_ have stopped to declare. But even if he did, it is unlikely that the authorities can determine that now.

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't passed through the customs. I am planning to travel again but I am afraid that I may have violated something and they will not allow me to leave again.

Comment: @user85638: How are you so sure of that? It seems much more likely that you did in fact pass through customs (there's usually _no other way out_ from the baggage hall) but you were just not aware that the corridor you walked through was actually customs.

Comment: There are many custom unions, so customs could be closed when arriving on some flights (when risk is low).

Comment: I remember that when I arrived at the airport is I that I went through the immigrations then I get my luggage and went right out through the exit.  Then when I arrived at my country I just did the same thing.  Will this going to have an affect in my next travel? I'm sorry I'm not that fluent in english.  Thanks

Comment: @user85638: we cannot answer: we lack too many information. Often countries do no track who pass on custom (but they will do random check) [but some requires a form, so they potentially know if someone passed. But again: we have no enough information to answer you.

Comment: @user85638: Since you seem to be refusing to say which location this happened in, we can't say anything definite. But in the vast majority of airports I know of, "went right out through the exit" means passing customs. That exit **IS CUSTOMS**.

Comment: @user85638 Also, it may appear that there’s no-one on duty but I’m pretty sure there’ll always be CCTV coverage and someone monitoring that out of sight

Comment: @user85638 please tell us where you travelled to and/or from. For example when entering Germany, you don't have to stop and fill out a customs declaration form. All you do is choose the red or green exit ([as shown in this picture](https://www.flughafen-stuttgart.de/media/98678/gesamt_ausgang.jpg)) - and exiting through the green gate is equivalent to a customs declaration ("I have nothing to declare").

Comment: Even the red zones don't always have anyone in them. I once hung around one for a few minutes because I wanted to declare something, and gave up waiting.

Comment: I'm not aware of any airport that's so poorly designed that it is possible to accidentally leave the airport without going through customs/immigration. That would rather defeat the purpose of the checkpoints.

Comment: Another possibility is the country you traveled to had a preclearance facility in the country you departed from, such as the facility the US has at Dublin Airport. US-bound travelers clear immigration and customs while still in Ireland, and wait in a special waiting area. When they arrive in the US, they leave the airport the same way domestic passengers do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Some airports have gates that can alternate between international and domestic flights, and if the airline or airport forget to configure the gate correctly, this can happen (there was a WestJet flight in Canada a year or two where this happened) - but it's not something that happens as a general rule.

Comment: Hi guys,  thank you for answering my question. It turned out I did passed through the customs, I was just expecting there are some process like in the immigrations.